# Encode Side by Side Video Sync'd by Audio (FFMPEG or similar)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am trying to encode 2 videos side by side, sync'd by the audio of the 2 clips. I can successfully encode the 2 videos side by side and select the audio from one of the input streams. However the system we are using to record the 2 videos does not start and stop the recording at the same time (could be up to a second different between cameras). Basically we are using a CCTV system to capture what's going on in a room from multiple angles. We export the 2 cameras between 2 timestamps and due to the way the system records the videos the start of the 2 clips are not the same point in time.

e.g. Export videos between 09:00:00:000 and 09:10:00:000

Video 1 - exports from 08:59:59:123 to 09:10:00:123

Video 2 - exports from 08:59:59:789 to 09:10:00:789

Therefore when video 1 and video 2 are stitched together side by side, they are out of sync by 666ms (which is very noticeable in the encoded video)

Both input streams have (near) identical audio and are both in the exact same format.  We are currently placing these videos into Premiere Pro and syncing these videos by the audio and exporting them side by side, however we have a project where we need to do a lot of these in quick succession and this is not really an option.  We need to look at scripting this.

Does anyone know if FFMPEG can do this?  Or anything else?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [audio-offset-finder](https://github.com/bbc/audio-offset-finder) in bash file to calculate offset, cut of the head from one of the video, stitch them together ( [like stated here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other) ).

You would need to extract audio streams into separate files and use finder to calculate offset.

```
offset=`audio-offset-finder --find-offset-of file1.wav --within file2.wav`
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will take a look at that,  very good of the BBC to publish that!